# Can first Python argparse positional argument only be of type str?

Tags: python, argparse

Am I right in the assumption that the first mandatory, positional argument added to `argparse.ArgumentParser()` instance can only be of type `str`?

When I set it to `float` (or `int`) and run the script in a shell, I get an *invalid float value* error. I doesn't matter whether I really pass in a `float` or even call `-h` for help, which should skip the parameter input and jump straight to the help section.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    prog="add-expense"
)

parser.add_argument(
    "Amount",
    type=float
)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

When I place another `parser.add_argument()` of default type `str` before it, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an added

```
print(args)
```

your script runs fine:

```
1013:~/mypy$ python3 stack69887099.py -h
usage: add-expense [-h] Amount

positional arguments:
  Amount

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
1013:~/mypy$ python3 stack69887099.py 1.232
Namespace(Amount=1.232)
1013:~/mypy$ python3 stack69887099.py test
usage: add-expense [-h] Amount
add-expense: error: argument Amount: invalid float value: 'test'
```